# Proving a property of hitting times of a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

I'm reading the course notes of a probability course about martingales currently and I'm trying to solve some of the exercises, however I'm very much stuck with the following exercise:

Let $\left\{ X_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$
  be a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$
  started at $X_{0}=a$
 . Given $b\in\mathbb{Z}$
  denote by $T_{b}$ the first hitting time of $b$
 , show that $\mathbb{E}_{a}\left[T_{b}|\, T_{b}<T_{0}\right]=\frac{b^{2}-a^{2}}{3}$
 .

Hint: Show that $M_{n}:=X_{n}^{3}-3nX_{n}$  is a martingale  and use the fact that $\left|M_{\min\left(T_{b},n\right)}\right|\leq b^{3}+3bT_{b}$

I've shown that indeed that is a martingale but I have no idea how to proceed, help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which uses have martingales, in general?

Comment: The only intuition I got is that Martingales are supposed to represent a "fair game/gamble", beyond that I'm not very comfortable with the concept or its uses...
It would be nice if people that down voted would at least explain the reasoning behind their down vote. Obviously I'm having difficulty or I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Honestly, what is a bit surprising is that you do not seem to be even aware of the mammoth result in this field, called the stopping time theorem.

Comment: @Did I've looked up the theorem and I see it's indeed a very powerful result. But I'm not sure the condition here meets the criteria of the theorem, the third condition requires that $\left|M_{\min\left(T_{b},n\right)}\right|\leq c$ a.s for every $n$, but the bound I have depends on $T_{b}$.

I apologize if the question seems banal to some but I've been glaring at this for some time now and I'm not making much progress myself, I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: can you show that $T_b$ is integrable?, i.e. $\mathbb{E}_aT_b<\infty$. If so, then option sampling theorem applies, because your martingale is bounded by a random variable which is integrable. $|M_{\min(T_b,n)}|\leq c$ is sufficient but not necessarily (effectively, you need to apply the dominated convergent theorem, bounded by an $L^1$ R.V. is sufficient)

Comment: @lost1 I can show that $T_{b}$ is integrable but I'm not sure how to finish the proof. What I don't see is how to use the optional stopping theorem to reach the required result.

Comment: okay, i will write something

Comment: Are you assuming that $a$ is between $0$ and $b$? If so, you should add that assumption to the statement of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional samping theorem holds for every **bounded** stopping time.

Consider the stopping time $\min(T_0,T_b,n)$ where $T_0$ is the first time the Markov Chain hits $0$, then

$|M_{\min(T_0,T_b,n)}|\leq b^3+3b\min(T_0,T_b)$, the right handside is integrable.

Optional Sampling theorem says

$\mathbb{E}_a M_{\min(T_0,T_b,n)}  = \mathbb{E}_a M_0$

since the right hand side is bounded by an integrable random varaible, we take $n$ to infinity and get

$\mathbb{E}_a M_{\min(T_0,T_b) }=a^3$

so the left handside equals to

$\mathbb{P}_a(T_b<T_0)(b^3 - 3b \mathbb{E}_aT_b1_{\{T_b<T_0\}}) + \mathbb{P}_a(T_0<T_b)(0) = a^3$

Note that $X$ is also a martingale, so $\mathbb{P}_a(T_b<T_0)=a/b$ (apply OTS to $X$). This means

$$\frac{b^2-a^2}{3} = \mathbb{E}_aT_b1_{\{T_b<T_0\}}$$

Comment: this only gives $ET_b$, need a bit more than this. I am editting.

Comment: Doesn't $\min\left(T_{b},n\right)$ need to be bounded by a constant that doesn't depend on $n$ in order to use the OST in that fashion?

Comment: @NewGuy $min(T_b,n)$ is bounded by $n$, for each $n$, then you take the limit because the RANDOM VARIABLES are bounded. Optional Sampling theorem only tells you $EX_T=EX_0$ when $T$ is a bounded stopping time for 1 bounded stopping time... very rarely are stopping times you are interested in are actually bounded...

Comment: @NewGuy something is wrong here, because $ET_b$ should be infinite for a random walk... also please check your question again and confirm that it is correct

Comment: @NewGuy so $T_b$ is not actually integrable...

Comment: Sorry about that, I seem to have gotten confused with another result about hitting times for a simple random walk..
I suppose you can just delete the answer now. If you have an alternative solution to the question it would be appreciated...

Comment: @NewGuy see edit.

Comment: That is a nice trick with defining that stopping time, I've definitely learnt something. Thanks!

Comment: @NewGuy btw, Could have use the optional stopping theorem version (2) on wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem the increment is bounded by 1. Also in this question $T_b$ and $T_0$ both appear so it was the right to consider their min. Morever $E\min(T_0,T_b)$ is finite, whereas $ET_b$ is not.

Comment: Thank you very much Lost1 for the help and the patience. Again apologies for my silly mistake.